# OpenCV python error (-215) photo found 50% of time

Tags: python, opencv

Using Opencv 3.1.0-dev, python 2.7.3 running through OS X terminal

I am running images through a stitching program I made and it works great. I use argparse to make it so I only have to pass a folder location and it will use all the photos in that folder to stitch. I had two test images and it worked great and made some other examples in different folders and with different numbers of images and worked but I am now running into an issue where I get this error:

```
img1 =  cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,imagesToStitch[0]),1),imageSize)
cv2.error: /Users/chrisradford/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3490: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function resize.
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
import cv2
import argparse
from StitchingMaster import Stitcher

#initalize objects
stitcher = Stitcher()
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-1", "--first", required=True)
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
#Define variables
imageSize = (1800,1200)                     #size of image to be passed      to stitcher
showMatches = False                         #True if wish to see   matches; False otherwise
keypoints = []
descriptors = []
resultImageSize = (1200,900)                #Size of final image to be displated and saved
imagesToStitch = os.listdir(args["first"])  #list of images in folder
path = os.path.abspath(args["first"])       #Folder path

#----Base Case[0-1]----#
if len(imagesToStitch) < 2:
    print "Not enough images to stitch"
    quit()
#----Base Case[2]----#
else:
    img1 =  cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,imagesToStitch[0]),1),imageSize)
    img2 = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,imagesToStitch[1]),1),imageSize)
    #result = stitched image
    (result,keypoints,descriptors) = stitcher.stitch([img1,img2],showMatches,keypoints,descriptors)
```

The error appears right after the

```
else: 
    img1 = cv2.resize....
```

I made another program that both opened the image at that location and resized it and it worked fine. Could it be the naming convention of the folder that gets messed up when I use `os.path.abspath()` and `os.listdir()`?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: split line into many lines and check results of every command using `print()` - maybe you get wrong path, wrong image, wrong imageSize, or image is empty and has no size, etc.

Comment: and [use Google to search this error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=opencv+ssize.width+%3E+0+%26%26+ssize.height+%3E+0+in+function+resize.&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=5-97WPrcA4vX6QTXzZfICg)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Already tried that and for some reason if I put a print anywhere in the code the error still appears even if the print statement is before the line causing the error. And yes google has been my go to all day today. Also thanks for editing the post for me.

Comment: you have to split line with problem to separated commands and check which element makes problem. Check if path is OK, then check if `imageSize` is OK, then check if readed image is OK - check its size before you resize. And this way you may find what makes problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further analysis I was able to determine that the issues was with:

```
os.listdir(args["first"])
```

This function also picks up hidden files.  Since I am running on OS X it also picked up the hidden file called:

```
.DS_Store
```

To solve I created a simple for loop checker that removes any such file that started with a "." from my list.

```
 for files in fileList:
     if not files.startswith('.'):
         imagesToStitch.append(files)
```